# SessionID is not shown in URL

Tags: php, apache

I would like to have the SessionID visible in the URL (for some security testing, I know it should not be!), so I set the PHP Settings accordingly:

```
session.use_cookies Off
session.use_only_cookies    Off
session.use_trans_sid   1
```

However, when I access my page, I still get no SID in URL and I see the following HTTP Header:

Cookie:PHPSESSID=sr50lafvtu9vkm0dcnc4m4lhm2

What am I missing?

Comment: Use phpinfo() to check whether your settings are actually applied.

Comment: Where did you set this settings? In php.ini or .htaccess?

Comment: Looking at the syntax, I'm guessing `php.ini` ... did you reboot Apache after making the changes?

Comment: Those settings are taken from the phpinfo output, so they are applied